# How to dynamically generate sql statements that converts any CLOB to varchar2

Tags: sql

I am generating sql statements using this sql:

`select 'select ' || listagg(t.column_name, ', ') within group (order by column_id, table_name) ||'  from &#source_table# a' query from user_tab_cols t where t.table_name = '&#target_table#';`

In some cases the columns I in the statement I generate are CLOB and I want to convert these to varchar2 using the following statement:
dbms_lob.substr (column, 4000, 1) as column and in other cases I want to remove the CLOB column, this I can control with a parameter.

How do I write the sql query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to create it using a case and a decode in the listagg:

```
select ' || listagg(
case t.data_type 
  when 'CLOB' then 
    decode('&#ignore_clob#',
    'no', 'dbms_lob.substr ('||t.column_name||', 4000, 1) as '|| t.column_name, 
    'yes','')
    else t.column_name
end
  , ', ') within group (order by column_id, table_name) ||
'  from #source_table a' query
from user_tab_cols t where t.table_name = '&#source_table#';
```